# Retrieve history of consumed item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In my android games, i have in app purchase that sell multiple item at once, i.e. Get 5000 coins + remove ads. It means that i have consumable and non consumable item at once. 
The problem is about restoring purchases. I know i can restore non consumable purchase, but since my IAP is consist both consumable and non consumable, i am having trouble restoring the purchase , because i will consume the product.

Is there a way to retrieve purchase details of an item once the consumed is completed?

Answer (score 4):

Just create an additional consumable item for purchasing additional coins beyond the first 5,000, and consume that one as usual, immediately after it is purchased, recording the 5,000 coin increment yourself, just as is done in the TrivialDrive IAB example.

When the initial purchase of your combined remove ads/Get 5,000 coins item is made, do not consume that item - treat it as non-consumable - but treat the purchase event itself as a one-time trigger for performing the same logic as you would when consuming your "buy additional 5,000 coins" item.

Remember that "consumable" and "non-consumable" items are not different from one another so far as the Google side of this process is concerned.  They are consumable or non-consumable only by virtue of the decision made in your code to consume them and record the increments to consumable resources internally, or to leave them there as a permanent record of the fact that the purchase has occurred.  Leaving the item there makes it visible on all user devices that support IAB, whereas the consumable items must be recorded (and shared between devices) by other means (e.g., in your app's own database in the cloud).

So, an alternative to the above would be to immediately consume the purchase of the remove ads / add 5,000 coins item, and record that ads are permanently removed, and that the user has 5,000 coins, in your own database. Then, that item could be re-purchased by the user, with the turning off of ads as a redundant no-op, and only the 5,000 coin increment being recorded.

But that second approach would only confuse your users, because the item would still be called "Remove ads/ get 5,000 coins," even after ads had already been removed.  Also, the approach I've outlined at the start ofthis answer would allow you to create any number of coin purchase items, with not only 5,000 coins, but other amounts, as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me clarify the flow of your 1st approach. CMIIW. I need to setup multiple IAP items. 1st is Get5000+remove ads, 2nd is 15000+remove ads, 3rd is additional 5000 coins, 4th is additional 15000 coins. Then user buy 5000+remove ads at first, and if they want to purchase additional coins, they need to buy the 3rd or 4th item. In that case, i think it will cause confusion for user, because it will become too many item in the list.

Comment: Actually, my games is local, so i don't have external database and my IAP item right now is 5000coins,15000coins+remove ads,25000+remove ads. Notice the 1st one is without remove ads. What i am trying to do is being able to restore the remove ads when user bought the 2nd item onwards. I was hoping google stored history of the purchase even if it is already consumed.

Comment: If you don't have a database in the cloud, then my first approach above should work for you, as it retains the "remove ads plus buy coins" item on Google's servers and thus allows your app to remove ads regardless of the device from which a user who has purchased that feature runs it.  As for having additional items for buying additional coins being confusing, I would say that trying to re-use your item combining ad removal with coins for additional coin purchases would be much *more* confusing.  But to be even less confusing, just have a separate item for removing ads and others for coins.

Comment: @Carl thanks! I understood more from your 5 paragraphs on IAP than from pages and pages of google documentation!

Answer (score 1):

First, In In-app billing V3, you can consume a managed item. Basically, you shouldn't be using any un-managed items in V3. Create a managed item, purchase it and consume it. if the result code for consume call is *BILLING_RESULT_OK*, provide the benefits to the user.

Coming to your question, It's your responsibility to track and manage products if you consume it.

**EDIT:**

Another way you can try is, create 4 iap items for the 4 buttons. Keep a track in your app for all iap items which are responsible for unlocking the ads. when user clicks on the button, check respective iap item is already owned or not using *getSkuDetails()*. If yes, consume it and purchase it. if not, directly purchase it (*unlock ads if the iap item is responsible to unlocks ads*). Don't consume the iap item now.

In *oncreate()*, check all owned items using *getSkuDetails()*. If any one of the owned items is responsible to unlock ads, and if the ads are not already unlocked, unlock ads(*restore*).

Comment: I think if I implement your method, when user click 'get 5000 points+unlock ads', user will be prompted a dialog to enter password, and after it succeeded user will be prompted again to unlock ads. It means double effort is needed. And if that is the case, I need to make the ads removal free item, that I think is can't be done. And even it can, the double prompt will be annoying, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It's annoying that the purchase window open twice for a single purchase. Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer.